# How to run powershell script file from JScript?

Tags: powershell, jscript, wscript.shell

I am trying to run powershell script from JScript.
powershell will pop up but the script is not getting executed.

Below is the sample code

```
var WSH = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var exec= WSH.Exec("powershell .\test1.ps1");
exec.StdIn.Close();
```

test1.ps1 is a simple script which creates textfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the full path to `c:\path\to\test1.ps1`. I guess there is a different idea of "the current directory" which `.\` is not finding the right file. Also try putting `-NoExit` on the end of the powershell command line, and maybe the window will stay open and you can read any error message.

Comment: changed it to full path with -NoExit , the error was because of ExecutionPolicy of powershell. It worked after fixing the path and executionpolicy like this WSH.Exec("powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned  c:\path\to\test1.ps1")